# Converting to JSON, how do I include multi-level deep models?

Tags: ruby

A has_many Bs
B has_many Cs
B belongs_to A
C belongs_to B
C belongs_to A

But when I do `myA.to_json(:include => [:b, :c])`, Everything is in teh top level, which makes sense, but how does one pass params to to_json such that Cs will be in an array made under B, and not A??

I think it should look something like this: `myA.to_json(:include => [:b => :c])` 
 I would read this as myA, to json, while including b, which includes c.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
myA.to_json(:include => { :b => { :include => :c } })
```

Comment: when I did as you suggested, I got this error: TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Hash, I'm using rails 2.3.8

Comment: oh, hey, I need to include :include for the nested stuff. I'll update your answer for you.